# VBA MSFORMS vs Controls - whats the difference

Tags: vba, userform

When adding controls to a userform, what is the difference between the following.  I am confused as to when it is appropriate to use any particular one of these.

```
Dim aButton1 as MSFORMS.CommandButton
Dim aButton2 as Control.CommandButton
Dim aButton3 as CommandButton
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Add UserForm first**. Then in **VBA IDE press F2**, the **object browser** appears. In the upper left corner is combo box, select **MSForms**. In the classes list you can see the classes which belongs to MSForms object library.

You can see **CommandButton** and **Control** in that list:

[image]

**To declare a variable of type CommandButton in your code:**

```
Dim button1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim button2 As CommandButton
```

The variable button1 is of type CommandButton from MSForms for sure. The **button2 could be your own class defined in your local VBA Project** ... but if your local VBA project doesn't contain any class with such name it will be considered from MSForms as well. However **if you reference another object library** say 'MSFoo' which will contain class CommandButton as well you will have to declare them **fully qualified** like this:

```
Dim button1 As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim button2 As MSFoo.CommandButton
```

**To declare a variable of type Control in your code:**

```
Dim controlObject As MSForms.Control
```

Use variable of type Control like kind of a base class for controls. E.g. to enumarate Controls collection:

```
For Each controlObject In Me.Controls
    Debug.Print VBA.TypeName(controlObject)
Next controlObject
```

Or as a parameter in function which expects not just only one type of control:

```
Private Sub PrinControlName(ByRef c As MSForms.Control)
    Debug.Print c.Name
End Sub
```

So using fully qualified names like MSForms.CommandButton is in general approprite i think. Using Control.CommandButton is wrong and won't compile until you reference some object library named 'Control' with class CommandButton in it.

**EDIT:**

Here an example of **locally created class with same name** like MSForm.CommandButton:
[image]

And how **TypeName** and **TypeOf** work in this case:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_buttonMsForms As MSForms.CommandButton
Private m_buttonLocal As CommandButton

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_buttonMsForms = Me.Controls.Add( _
        "Forms.CommandButton.1", "testMsButton", True)
    Set m_buttonLocal = New CommandButton

    m_buttonLocal.Name = "testLocalButton"

    Debug.Print "We have two instances of two different button types: " & _
        m_buttonLocal.Name & " and " & m_buttonMsForms.Name

    ' Check instances with TypeName function
    ' TypeName function returns same results
    If VBA.TypeName(m_buttonMsForms) = VBA.TypeName(m_buttonLocal) Then
        Debug.Print "TypeName of both buton types returns same result"
    End If

    ' Check instances with TypeOf operator
    ' TypeOf doen't work with not initialised objects
    If m_buttonLocal Is Nothing Or m_buttonMsForms Is Nothing Then _
        Exit Sub

    ' TypeOf operator can distinguish between
    ' localy declared CommandButton type and MSForms CommandButton
    If TypeOf m_buttonLocal Is MSForms.CommandButton Then _
        Debug.Print "m_buttonLocal Is MSForms.CommandButton"

    If TypeOf m_buttonMsForms Is CommandButton Then _
        Debug.Print "m_buttonMsForms Is CommandButton"

    If TypeOf m_buttonLocal Is CommandButton Then _
        Debug.Print "m_buttonLocal Is CommandButton"

    If TypeOf m_buttonMsForms Is MSForms.CommandButton Then _
        Debug.Print "m_buttonMsForms Is MSForms.CommandButton"

End Sub
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> We have two instances of two different button types: testLocalButton and testMsButton
> TypeName of both buton types returns same result
> m_buttonLocal Is CommandButton
> m_buttonMsForms Is MSForms.CommandButton
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Numbers 1 and 3 create the same type of control. The first statement is just fully qualified - equivalent to using Dim ws as WorkSheet or Dim ws as Excel.WorkSheet.

I'm not familiar with the 2nd type - "Control.CommandButton" - and it doesn't compile for me inside a userform in Excel 2010.